# how do I do file-listing of all files/packages in an .iso to stdout or to a file?

Tags: debian, iso, distribution-media

I am looking to do a file-listing of all files/packages in an .iso either to stdout or to a file. It would be nice if the file-listing is complete as in `$ls -l` so I have all the necessary data to manipulate and take a call based on the data I have. I don't want to mount the .iso but read through it. as I would a directory.

Look forward to know.

Answer (score 2):

You can mount the .iso file:

```
# mount -o loop file.iso /mnt
# ls -lR /mnt
```

Comment: @cas thank you for attempting, have updated my question so you know what I mean. There is a software which does what I want but have forgotten it. Any ideas ?